# Fancyhdr not working for articles more than 10 pages long

Tags: fancyhdr, article, pagestyle

I am writing a chapter in `article` class. Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\if\thepage\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\small\emph{Compiled by:} XYZ
    \else \relax
    \fi}
\fancyfoot[R]{\if\thepage\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\small Page \thepage~of \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}
    \else \relax
    \fi}
\fancyfoot[C]{\if\thepage\getpagerefnumber{LastPage} \relax
    \else \small Page \thepage~of \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}
    \fi}
\title{Title}
\author{ABC}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        Title
    \end{titlepage}
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \section{Objectives}
%   \lipsum[1-40] %Toggle this and the following length of the document
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

**My goal:** Print `Page # of #(last page)` at the center footer in all but the last page. In the last page, left footer will contain the message `Compiled by: XYZ` and the right footer will contain `Page # of #(last page)`, whereas the center footer will be blank.

As long as the length of the document after the `Contents` page is less than 10 pages, it is working as expected. But for longer documents, it is misbehaving after the 10th page onwards. Please help.

Comment: What exactly are those if statements suppose to do? If you're not careful you en up comparing 1 and 0 in the number 10 or something similar. Why if why not ifnum?

Comment: \if expands and then compares. So if the page is 10 it will compare 1 with 0.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How to get around that?

Comment: `\ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}`  should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. It works. Why don't you convert your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\ifnum` to compare numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage,refcount}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\small\emph{Compiled by:} XYZ  \fi}
\fancyfoot[R]{\ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\small Page \thepage~of \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\fi}
\fancyfoot[C]{\ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage} \relax
    \else \small Page \thepage~of \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\fi}
\title{Title}
\author{ABC}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        Title
    \end{titlepage}
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \section{Objectives}
%   \lipsum[1-40] %Toggle this and the following length of the document
    \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd reverse the order, just for safety. True, `\small` doesn't begin with digits, but…

Answer (score 3):

While there's an accepted answer on this, there are a couple things worth nothing.

**Conditionals in (La)TeX**

This is a big source of confusion for people, given the profusion of `\ifXXX` commands in TeX.

The command `\if` is usually *not* what we want. It will expand what follows it until it gets two unexpandable tokens. So `\if\thepage\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}...\fi` will first expand `\thepage` which is going to expand to the digits of the page number. If it's a single digit, it will expand `\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}` which will again expand into digits.¹ But if it's two digits, then it's going to stop there in the comparison and compare the first two digits of the page number, so the `\if` will be true for pages 11, 22, 33, …, 110–119, 220–229, etc.

The solution, as Ulrike noted is to use `\ifnum` with `\value{page}`².

I'd recommend looking at chapter 20 of *The TeXbook* which goes into some depth into the different kinds of comparisons that are available at a primitive level.

**But is that really what you want?**

The thing is, that the current solution is not necessarily the right way to get a different headers on the final page. Rather than putting some logic into the page style which has to be executed on every page, it makes far more sense to instead just change the page style on the last page. Remember that LaTeX has a command `\thispagestyle` which changes the page style for the current page. It's most commonly used for the first page of a chapter or article, but it can be used anywhere. It's not uncommon for a book to have a page number at the bottom of every page except the last page of a chapter. Implementing this in LaTeX is simply a matter of executing `\thispagestyle{empty}` *before* the `\clearpage`³ command that opens the chapter.

Similarly, by doing something like

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small Page \thepage~of \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}

\fancypagestyle{lastpage}{%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\small\emph{Compiled by:}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\small Page \thepage~of \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}}
}

\AddToHook{enddocument}{\thispagestyle{lastpage}}
```

You can get your special formatting on the last page of the document.⁴

---

1. Although it's worth noting that slightly different mechanisms are used in the two cases and there's no guarantee that `\thepage` will give arabic digits—for example, if you turn on `\pagenumbering{roman}` it will give `i`, `ii`, etc. whereas `\getpagerefnumber` goes to some lengths to make sure that it always gives a numeric answer.
2. We could kind of get away with using `\thepage` except that there's no generic guarantee that `\thepage` will expand to a number, (page numbers might print as i, ii, iii, … or 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, … or any number of non-numeric strings).
3. Or `\cleardoublepage` as the case may be.
4. With one limitation, which may or may not be a problem for your use case—if there are any deferred floats that would be printed at the end of the document, this page style will apply to the last text page but not the pages with the floats that follow. I suspect, though, that this might actually be preferred behavior for your document if that were to occur.

   Another possible solution for this situation might be to instead use `\pagestyle{lastpage}` instead of `\thispagestyle{lastpage}` (which would make the most sense in the case where you were switching to blank pages).